# Express and next method usage without return

Tags: node.js, express

In express, we can call the `next()` or `next(Error)` method to call the next function.
I made a beginner error by implementing the following code:

```
if(error) {
    next(new Error('This is an error');
}
console.log("Don't display this if error.");
```

Big issue as after the call of the `next` method the text is printed in the console. I had to change the code by the following:

```
if(error) {
    return next(new Error('This is an error');
}
console.log("Don't display this if error.");
```

Now, it is working fine.

My question: Is there any benefit to call the next methode outside a return statement?
My understanding is that this will create a multi path execution very difficult to debug/maintain.

Comment: You could obviously put the "Don't display..." message inside an `else` branch. I am not sure what maintenance worry you have however. It could be a problem I suppose if you inconsistently employ multiple approaches, but the `return next()` (or `return res.send()`, etc, idiom is pretty common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer to the original question, yes there's value in not returning next(). concrete example: you  have an express app and you define an error handler middleware function to use. Now, in that function you attach the error to say connect-flash for later retrieval in a jade template and display to the user via Bootstrap notifications.

Now, you don't want to leave your original callback execution by returning next(). Assume you submitted a form to the server, an error happens and now you have to re-render the data in your jade template before returning to the browser. Hence, you will still continue to execute and return your original function(req, res, next) and render the response but via connect-flash Jade will inject also the error message and you simply have a "controlled rendering in case of error" rather than funnel all issues to a common "Opps something broke" page.

Also calling next() simply invokes the next middleware on the execution pipeline (hence why it's important the order you declare the app.use middleware). You can auth or you can do many amazing things via node.js middleware. In you case, calling Next with an err will bypass all normal middleware and execute the 4 params error handler (as per express specs).

Comment: Thank you, your answer is clear for me. Actualy I am working only with REST interface without JADE etc. But we can certainly have a use case where we would like to enrich a REST response with an error context. If you have one in mind, could you please kindly share it with us?

Comment: Sure, assume you want to send the actual errors to a log sink and still return to finish the original callback code to do some unwinding or similar of your original call, or any extra cleanup you might need.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you to think of your code as follows:

```
if(error) {
    // Let somebody else do something with the error.
    next(error);

    // Don't to anything else here.
    return;
}

console.log("No error, then do something here");
```

Using `return next(error)` is just a shorter way of writing that.